# Angular 4 - access formControl state through ng-content

Tags: css, angular

I want to create custom styling for my form elements. Therefore I have to add a parent element to each input and select element. The parent element will contain the CSS classes for the styling. Example:

```
<div class="o-form-field is-valid">
  <input formControlName="foo">
</div>
<div class="o-form-field is-invalid">
  <input formControlName="bar">
</div>
<div class="o-form-field has-error">
  <input formControlName="baz">
</div>
```

I am looking for a solution where I can replace the outer DIV with a component that watched the child input state and figures out what classes are needed. Renders the DIV in it's template and transcludes the input element. So my form template would look something like this.

```
<form-field-container>
  <input formControlName="foo">
</form-field-container>
<form-field-container>
  <input formControlName="bar">
</form-field>
<form-field-container>
  <input formControlName="baz">
</form-field>
```

I am using Reactive forms.

Comment: You can pass a `statusChanges` observable as a prop to your wrapper component, subscribe there and act according to status messages. These observables are accessible as `yourForm.get('bar').statusChanges` etc.

Comment: Any chance you know how to listen for state changes like 'touched' and 'dirty'?